# Exporting to XML via built in python

Tags: python, xml

I'm extremely new to python and am trying to export some xml to an xml file via a python script. I am having trouble nesting a child within a child. the code i have been trying to emulate is this

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.Document()

root = doc.createElement('root')
doc.appendChild(root)

leaf = doc.createElement('leaf')
text = doc.createTextNode('Text element with attributes')
leaf.appendChild(text)
leaf.setAttribute('color', 'white')
root.appendChild(leaf)

leaf_cdata = doc.createElement('leaf_cdata')
cdata = doc.createCDATASection('<em>CData</em> can contain <strong>HTML tags</strong> without encoding')
leaf_cdata.appendChild(cdata)
root.appendChild(leaf_cdata)

branch = doc.createElement('branch')
branch.appendChild(leaf.cloneNode(True))
root.appendChild(branch)

mixed = doc.createElement('mixed')
mixed_leaf = leaf.cloneNode(True)
mixed_leaf.setAttribute('color', 'black')
mixed_leaf.setAttribute('state', 'modified')
mixed.appendChild(mixed_leaf)
mixed_text = doc.createTextNode('Do not use mixed elements if it possible.')
mixed.appendChild(mixed_text)
root.appendChild(mixed)

xml_str = doc.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
with open("minidom_example.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(xml_str)
```

i am trying to output the following to a single xml file

```
 <sources>
  <sourcecat sourcecatname="CATEGORY NAME">
   <source type="gen_xmltv" channels="path/path1/">
    <description>Description</description>
    <url>http://urlhere</url>
  </source>
 <source type="gen_xmltv" channels="path/path2/">
    <description>Description</description>
    <url>http://urlhere</url>
  </source>
  <source type="gen_xmltv" channels="path/path3/">
    <description>Description</description>
    <url>http://urlhere</url>
  </source>
 </sourcecat>
```

i can it all outputed except for the sourcecat closing / it puts it on the same line as 
  
meaning i want to nest sourcecat inside sources and also nest all the 3 parts within the sourcecat also. 
no matter where i put appendChild(sourcecat) it closes it on the same line.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Very nice [mcve] question.

Comment: There's a pretty big difference between the sample output and what your code produces, and some of the difference looks like it's deliberate.  For example, the code includes a CDATA section but there's no CDATA in the sample.  This makes it hard to tell what you intended and what is due to misunderstanding. Can you [edit] your post so the output differs from what the code produces only such that it highlights what you don't understand?

Comment: i was using that example as thats what i am following.. i amended the code to output.. i will redo it again later and post the code i am actualy using..i just wanted to know if there was a way to nest withina nest

Comment: Of course there is, that's the whole point of XML, but until your code and sample data match reality there's no point in anyone wasting time looking at it.  A simple rule here is _Make it easy for people to help you_.